# Cloud.orbit.exception.UncheckedException: Don't know how to handle state

Tags: java, kotlin

What is kotlin equivalent of this java class?

```
public class StatefulActor extends AbstractActor<StatefulActor.State> implements Some
{
    public static class State
    {
        String lastMessage;
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
class HelloActor: AbstractActor<HelloActor.State>(), Hello
{
    inner class State {
        var lastMessage: String? = null
    }
```

but results in `Cloud.orbit.exception.UncheckedException: Don't know how to handle state`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is kotlin equivalent of this java class?

Your Kotlin and Java code differs in two ways, the relationship of the `State` to `StatefulActor` and the ability of `State` to allow subclassing.

For `State` what you want is a [Nested](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#nested-classes) class not an [Inner](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#inner-classes) class in Kotlin terms. The former corresponds to `static` modifier in Java whereas the latter is like an inner class without the `static` modifier.

So for equivalence with the Java code you gave, you should drop the `inner` keyword.

> Cloud.orbit.exception.UncheckedException: Don't know how to handle state

As for your Orbit problem you can try the following. This will also explain why subclassing is an issue:

```kotlin
// compile and run with cloud.orbit:orbit-runtime:1.2.0

import cloud.orbit.actors.runtime.AbstractActor
import cloud.orbit.actors.Actor
import cloud.orbit.actors.Stage
import cloud.orbit.concurrent.Task

class HelloActor: AbstractActor<HelloActor.ActorState>(), Hello
{
    override fun sayHello(greeting: String): Task<String> {
        val lastMessage = state().lastMessage
        state().lastMessage = greeting

        return Task.fromValue(lastMessage)
    }

    class ActorState {
        var lastMessage: String? = null
    }
}

interface Hello : Actor {
    fun sayHello(greeting: String): Task<String>
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val stage = Stage.Builder().clusterName("orbit-helloworld-cluster").build()
    stage.start().join()
    stage.bind()

    val helloActor = Actor.getReference(Hello::class.java, "0");

    var response = helloActor
            .sayHello("Welcome to orbit 1").join()

    println(response) // should print null

    response = helloActor
            .sayHello("Welcome to orbit 2").join()

    println(response) // should print "Welcome to orbit 1"

    stage.stop().join()
}
```

Notice that the Actor's nested class is called `ActorState` and not `State` as in your question. When I named the Actor's state class `State` I got a similar error:

```
cloud.orbit.exception.UncheckedException: Don't know how to handle state: HelloActor$State...
Caused by: cloud.orbit.exception.UncheckedException: cloud.orbit.exception.UncheckedException: Don't know how to handle state: HelloActor$State
Caused by: cloud.orbit.exception.UncheckedException: Don't know how to handle state: HelloActor$State
Caused by: cloud.orbit.exception.UncheckedException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloActor$ActorState
```

But when I used the nested class name `HelloActor.ActorState` instead it works.

[This is because by default all classes in Kotlin are closed (i.e. `final` in Java terms).](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance)

> By default, all classes in Kotlin are final, which corresponds to Effective Java, Item 17: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it.

While in orbit 1.2.0 the [code](https://github.com/orbit/orbit/blob/v1.2.0/actors/core/src/main/java/cloud/orbit/actors/runtime/ActorFactoryGenerator.java#L349) (if you do not use the special name `ActorState`) tries to subclass your State class and then instantiate it. This will not work if you go with the closed Kotlin default extensibility.

If you wish to use your own name for the Actor's state class you must declare it as `open`. e.g.

```kotlin
class HelloActor: AbstractActor<HelloActor.State>(), Hello
{
    override fun sayHello(greeting: String): Task<String> {
        val lastMessage = state().lastMessage
        state().lastMessage = greeting

        return Task.fromValue(lastMessage)
    }

    open class State {
        var lastMessage: String? = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Same exception. Nothing changed

Comment: Try this full runnable example, it works for me. There seems to be some issue naming the Actor's State class `State` but `ActorState` works.

Comment: Why extend `Actor` in HelloActor?

Comment: It is not necessary. I left it in by accident. I've removed it now.